# Creating a new object from multiple destructured objects, what is the override order?

Tags: javascript, object

```
let x = {a: 'ax', b: 'bx'}
let y = {a: 'ay', c: 'cy'}

let z = {...x, ...y} // => {a: "ay", b: "bx", c: "cy"}
let z = {...y, ...x} // => {a: "ay", c: "cy", b: "bx"}
```

Why does `ay` always override the `a` value?

If I want to merge this way multiple objects, how do I know which will override which?

Comment: I don't see any destructuring in your code? And object spread is not in ES6.

Comment: The second `z` output will be `{a: "ax", c: "cy", b: "bx"}`

Comment: The right will override the left.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem: https://i.imgur.com/zpuOSYO.png

Comment: This is strange, the chrome console gave me `let z = {...y, ...x} // => {a: "ay", c: "cy", b: "bx"}` but when I tried copy-paste the whole thing it was `{a: "ax", c: "cy", b: "bx"}`

Comment: @ilyo: That's odd, can you post the exact sequence that lead you to the incorrect result? I don't see it when I try in the console: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8p0uC.png

Comment: @ilyo If you copy-pasted the *whole* thing you posted, it should have thrown a `SyntaxError: Identifier 'z' has already been declared`

Answer (score 0):

> Why does ay always override the a value?

It doesn't, it depends on the order `x` and `y` are listed (see below, your observation that `z.a` is always `"ay"` is mistaken). This is because properties in an object initializer are processed *in order*. It's the same reason that we end up with `o.a` being 42 here:

```
const o = {
    a: 67,
    a: 42
};
```

> ...what is the override order?

Last wins.

---

Note that the results are not what you've described:

```js
let x = {a: 'ax', b: 'bx'}
let y = {a: 'ay', c: 'cy'}

console.log({...x, ...y}) // => {a: "ay", b: "bx", c: "cy"}
console.log({...y, ...x}) // => {a: "ax", c: "cy", b: "bx"}
// Note -------------------------^^^^^^^
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: The OP is reporting that for `{...y, ...x}`, *first* wins.

Comment: @Quentin: If so, they're simply mistaken.

Comment: That or they have a weird, buggy JS engine.

Comment: @Quentin the last one wins.

Comment: @zabusa — that would be why I posted a comment on the question saying I couldn't reproduce the problem.